# Find characteristic function (probability)

Tags: probability-theory, density-function

Let $Z_k$ be a sequence of independent random variables so that $P(Z_k=1)=1/2,P(Z_k=-1)=1/2$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Also let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Z_k,G_n=\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. Show that the characteristic function of $G_n$ is

$$\psi_{G_n}(u)=\cos(\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}})^n$$. I know that $\psi_X(u):=E(e^{iux})$ and I know that the expected value can be written as an integral but I'm stuck on doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Exploit the following rules:

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent rv's then:$$\psi_{X+Y}(t)=\mathbb Ee^{it(X+Y)}=\mathbb Ee^{itX}e^{itY}=\mathbb Ee^{itX}\mathbb Ee^{itY}=\psi_X(t)\psi_Y(t)\tag1$$(this to find the characteristic function of $S_n$)

And for a constant $a$:$$\psi_{aX}(t)=\mathbb Ee^{itaX}=\psi_X(at)\tag2$$(this to find the characteristic function of $G_n$)

Comment: What I have now is $\psi_{G_n}(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n E(e^{i\sqrt{n}t Z_k})$. Also the expected value of $Z_k$ should be 0 because the probabilities for $Z_k=1$ being $1/2$ and $Z_k=-1$ being $1/2$ add up to 1? Or am I missing something? How do I continue?

Comment: $\psi_{Z_k}(t)=\frac12e^{-it}+\frac12e^{it}=\cos t$ for every $k$ so according to (1) $\psi_{S_n}(t)=\cos(t)^n$. Then apply (2) with $a=\frac1{\sqrt n}$.